# Backend javascript Service App using MSAL.JS

Tags: javascript, service, azure-ad-msal

I am creating a backend Javascript service app that will access the Microsoft Graph API on a recurring schedule..

I've been able to successfully call the Graph API using the v1 endpoint, but was hoping to do the same through the v2 endpoint using the MSAL for Javascript library:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js.

I found this link, which lays out the following C# code for accomplishing what I want to do:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // get access token including application permissions
  ConfidentialClientApplication cl = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/testdirectory.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0",
    "6abf3364-0a60-4603-8276-e9abb0d843d6",
    "https://localhost/testapp02",
    new ClientCredential("JfgrNM9CcW..."),
    new TokenCache());
  AuthenticationResult authResult = cl.AcquireTokenForClient(
    new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" },
    null).Result;

  Console.WriteLine(authResult.Token);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What I'm seeing on the MSAL Javascript documentation, though, is that there is no confidentialClientApplication Class in this library.

Is there another way to submit client credentials directly and bypass the login popup altogether?  Or, are there alternatives to this library I could consider?

Comment: You are correct, msal.js does not have this capability. It's primary use is for single page applications (client side) and is not capable of doing confidential client flows. What are you looking to do on the backend call? Are you trying to make requests on behalf of a user or across a directory? Is there a front end or client app involved?

Comment: @DanielDobalian, the backend (Node server) will call the Graph API to receive emails sent to a specific auto-reply address every few minutes.  It will parse and process requests sent in the body of the e-mails and then send requested reports to the sender.  There will eventually be a front end for starting/stopping the service manually, but not in this first iteration.